# Using a Variable within a name of a variable

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In PHP and a few other languages, I know that there is a way for a program to dynamically call the name of a control using Visual Basic.NET?

For example: if you have a control named `txtQuestionValue15.text` on a WinForm, is there a way to set up some kind of loop to go back and get through 1 through 14 and disable them, or do I have to manually edit in.

I was thinking of using something like this `SELECT Case` statement to try:

```
    Select Case trkNoOfQuestions.Value
        Case 1
        Case 2
        Case 3
        Case 4
        Case 5
        Case 6
        Case 7
        Case 8
        Case 9
        Case 10
        Case 11
        Case 12
        Case 13
        Case 14
        Case 15
            ' Enable Question 15
            txtQuestionTL15.Enabled = True
            txtQuestionTL15.Text = 45
            txtQuestionValue15.Enabled = True
            txtQuestionValue15.Text = 1000000

    End Select
```

Comment: there are several ways to do something like that -  store the names in a List and loop thru that - the list could contain a class which contains the `TL` and `Value` controls.

Comment: Use `DataGridView` control

Comment: Care to give an example of how to use a DataGridView in this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop and a string to find the control. You must check the control collection where they reside - here I am using the form.

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 15
 Dim tb As Textbox = TryCast(Me.Controls("txtQuestionTL" & i.ToString), Textbox)
 If Not tb Is Nothing Then 
 'now you have the textbox based on the name
 End If
Next
```

Alternatively you do a search no matter what container they live in:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 15
 Dim tbs = Me.Controls.Find("txtQuestionTL" & i.ToString, True)
 If tbs.Count > 0 Then
   Dim tb As TextBox = tbs.First 
 End If
Next
```

Comment: So would I have to use the name txtQuestionTL1 for the control or is there a way to express the loop as a two digit number?

Comment: Since `i` = 1 and not 01 just rename them to match the counter.